# Where and How to define Constant in Symfony?

Tags: symfony1

I have a few of my own constants in symfony, and I need to make them available throughout the application, where to best define them?

I tried, in the directory `myapps\config\config.php`, define my constant in this way:

```
sfConfig::set('aaa', 'mya');
```

But when I tried to access the constant in `myapps\apps\frontend\modules\login\actions\actions.class.php`, using this comand

```
sfConfig::get('aaa')
```

I simply get a null, indicating that it hasn't been defined.

How and where to define symfony constant so that it is accessible throughout the whole project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem:

Put the following into my `myapp/apps/frontend/config/app.yml`:

```
all:
  .app_set:
    bpobackend:       me
    bpoRedirectScreen:    allow
```

Then in action module, call the var_dump to check the value

```
var_dump(sfConfig::get('app_bpobackend'));
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are trying to use symfony 1.0 style configuration with symfony 1.1 or 1.2. [all config.php files have been removed in 1.1](http://www.symfony-project.org/installation/1_1/upgrade#config.php). see [Overview of the Configuration Files](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/05-Configuring-Symfony#chapter_05_overview_of_the_configuration_files) for what to use instead. and always be sure to look at the documentation for the proper version (*1_2* (or whatever version you are using) in the url).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to add constant in the config.php in Symfony 1.0..

So If you want to add constant variables in config.php then

```
sfConfig::add(array('SF_DEFAULT_DATEFORMAT' => 'dd-MM-yyyy'));
```

This is the code where I have define the date format with name 'SF_DEFAULT_DATEFORMAT'...

So You can Tried with this One ...